# On touch display a small view above that touched elements in android

Tags: android, view

Hi I do not know what is the exact word i am searching for. Like whatsapp when first touch of file attach icon a new small window( containing documents,camera,gallery, audio,location,contact) opens above or below the icon. i need the same type exactly . Help me out.

Comment: please share your code with error

Comment: You can use Dialog for that, use this library for implementing bottom dialog https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're talking about is a Circle Reveal. It's a relatively easy process, you just take a view, find the coordinates you want to animate the circle opening from, then set the view to animate. [Here is a tutorial](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-circular-reveal-effect-like-in-whatsapp.html) showing you how to do a Circle Reveal like they have in WhatsApp. Or you can just google for android circle reveal animation.

Comment: This exactly i  wanted . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking are know as `Bottom sheets` in android and `Action sheets` in ios.

> Bottom sheets slide up from the bottom of the screen to reveal more
> content.
>
> Action sheets are type of alert that appears in response to a
> control/action and presents a set of choices.

As you have tagged android in your question I suppose [this](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#) will reveal more minute details to you.